# Using Model.objects.all() as a blueprint for a secondary table entry

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am having a bit of trouble with the logic of how this should work so I am hoping it is possible.

**I figured out 1 possible solution that is written as an answer below, I will accept it in a few days, but if someone comes up with a better solution, I will negate any answer I post.**

Overall I am working on an Apartment Move-Out/Move-In Inspection Application in Django, and in both portions I have universal **Locations** that must be inspected for each report. I have allowed the `InspectionLocations` objects to be updated/submitted by clients, which is presenting an issue in how submitted reports should be stored in my Database.

What I want is to use the `InspectionLocations` table as a blueprint to build an Inspection Report for Move-Ins where the form-fields are generated based on the `InspectionLocations` objects' `location`, `status`, and `information` attributes/fields.

My issue is right at this point, how do I reference those values as a blueprint to build a report submission when the number of fields in the `InspectionLocations` can change?

```
from django.db import models
from apps.units.models import Unit

class Inspections(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    inspection_date = models.DateField()


    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.CustomUser',
        default=None,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        db_column='submitted_by')

    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)


class MoveInInspections(Inspections):
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='unit_id')
    # should have reference to all InspectionLocation items as reference for submission, how?



class MoveOutInspections(Inspections):
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='unit_id')
    date_notice_given = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    date_vacated = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
     # should have reference to all InspectionLocation items as reference for submission, how?



class InspectionLocations(models.Model):
    '''

    Defualt Inspection Locations are created when a 
    client is created using code like this:

    InspectionLocation.objects.get_or_create(location='Living Room')
    InspectionLocation.objects.get_or_create(location='Dining Room')
    InspectionLocation.objects.get_or_create(location='Kitchen')
    InspectionLocation.objects.get_or_create(location='Bedroom')
    InspectionLocation.objects.get_or_create(location='Bathroom')
    InspectionLocation.objects.get_or_create(location='Other')
    '''

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=None)
    information = models.TextField(default=None, blank=True)
```

I have tried ManyToMany fields and FKs but I cannot seem to get the logic working as anytime an object references an `InspectionLocations` object it is universally changing data for every report, which is leading be to the idea that I somehow need to use it as a **blueprint**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't post this in my question because it was getting long, but my best option so far seems to be to use a Django JSONField (as I am using Postgres), like so:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class MoveInInspections(Inspections):
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='unit_id')
    data = JSONField()



class MoveOutInspections(Inspections):
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='unit_id')
    date_notice_given = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    date_vacated = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    data = JSONField()
```

To where I store the values of the `InspectionLocations` object's in a Dictionary

Comment: This worked out pretty nicely today. Django's JSONField is nice... I once attempted to do this with MySQL and a textfield and it was inefficient as converting the json to a dict at runtime does not allow standard ORM queries... I'm hoping there is a better way for that reason, if there isn't please let me know